# Extending the automatically generated JPA controller (Netbeans 7.x)

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, controller, partial-classes

Netbeans 7.x offers the possibility to generate entities (POJOs) from an existing relational database (ex: CustomerEntity, OrderEntity, etc.)

Also, it generates automatically a controller for each entity (ex: CustomerJpaController, OrderJpaController, etc.).

The generated controllers contains many ready-to-use methods (findAll, create, delete, etc.). The advantage using this controllers' generator is the possibility to recreate/update them once an entity (or table) is modified (adding new constraints, new fields, etc.).

Unlike the "partial class" concept offered by .NET, it is not possible to extend these controllers with user-defined methods in separate classes.

What do you suggest (in terms of best practices or design patterns) to take advantage of these automatically generated controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I use the generated controller classes in self-created DAO classes.